# Automatically populating field on layer with geometry when corresponding field on layer without geometry is edited using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, qfield

I have a "Burn Plan" Form layer (no geometry) that has a "wind_direction" field whose widget is a Value Relation with 16 options to choose from (from a "directions" no-geometry layer).

[image]

I have a "Wind" (point geometry) layer that acts as a visual indicator on the map with Categorized Symbology to display as one of 16 different symbols based on its own "wind_direction" field.

[image]

I would like to have the "wind_direction" field in the "Wind" Point Geometry Layer automatically populate with whatever value is chosen in the "Burn Plan" field "wind_direction" to be able to display the proper symbol.

[image]

I've tried this a couple different ways, with Joins and with a "get_feature" expression in the "Wind" layer's "wind_direction" field. I admit, I may not be executing the Joins or writing the expressions properly, and couldn't find any answers that were quite the same thing as what I'm going for here.

I intend this project to be used in QField as well, so I'd like for this function to also work in QField.

Comment: Please share the expressions and Join settings you have tried or it's hard to figure out what didn't work. Assuming `burn_plan_uuid` is common to both layers (and unique in the Burn Plan layer), If you want to keep the existing `wind_direction` field in the Wind layer, then you can go to the Wind layer > Properties > Attributes Form > Apply default value for the `wind_direction` field and use this expression: `attribute(get_feature('Burn Plan','burn_plan_uuid',"burn_plan_uuid"),'wind_direction')` - take note of the single and double quotes

Comment: That is the same expression I used except I think I had the syntax wrong. At first, in the Expressions Window it says "Expression is invalid. Could not find 'burn_unit_uuid'" but then it shows the correct value (from 'burn_plan' layer) in the Attributes Form Preview, but the value doesn't change in the 'wind" layer attribute table.

The field 'burn_plan_uuid' is only on the 'burn_plan' layer. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong because the premise of a join is that there must be a common ID field that links the two layers together, and `get_feature()` relies on this. The field name doesn't have to be the same but the values have to match. How else will the Wind layer know which Burn Plan feature it should be looking at?